# jsp pass variables between two pages

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In my main jsp page, I have something like

```
<%@ include file="../customParametersHorizontal.jsp" %>

<tr>
<td align="center" class="ReportParamsGenerateButtonCell">
<html:submit onclick="if(preGenerateCriteria()){return true;} else {return false;}">Generate</html:submit>
</td>
</tr>
```

Within customParametersHorizontal.jsp, there is another include for dateSelection1.jsp, which validates date and time set on the form.

```
 <script>
function validateHHMM(inputField, message) {
    var isValid = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/.test(inputField);

    if (isValid) {

    }else {
        alert("Time must be entered in the format HH:MM AM/PM");

    }

    return isValid;
}
</script>
```

So, within dateSelection1.jsp, I tried to disable the button in the main jsp using :

```
 document.form1.ReportParamsGenerateButtonCell.disabled= true;
```

But, I get an error saying object is null or not defined.

Is there anyway, I can set a var, so that it can be chacked by the main form and disable the button accordingly?

Comment: Yeah, but you'd need to actually have a form element with that name and/or id (I forget which)--you don't at the moment. You have a table row with that class, but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, retaining the `<html:submit>` tag, and without introducing jQuery:  First, add the styleId attribute so that your button has an HTML ID you can grab onto:

```
<html:submit styleId="my_submit" onclick="if(preGenerateCriteria()){return true;} else {return false;}">Generate</html:submit>
```

Next, use the ID to get the element of the DOM and disable it:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("my_submit");
elt.disabled = true;
```

**Update**

If I understand the original question correctly, main.jsp includes customParametersHorizontal.jsp, whici includes dateSelection1.jsp.  So the three scripts are rendering just one HTML page, hence one document object.

I only see (partial) code for one `<form>` on the HTML page.  Even if you do have more than one form, .getElementById() works across all DOM elements in all forms, as opposed to the `document.form1` style of accessing elements.

Be sure that you call validateHHMM() at the appropriate point to enable/disable your submit button, and make sure that the button is re-enabled once the user corrects his input to make it valid.

Comment: How do I do it if it is across different pages?

Answer (score 1):

`document.form1.ReportParamsGenerateButtonCell` will return null or error unless you have the elements with name attribute set to `form1` and `ReportParamsGenerateButtonCell` like the example bellow:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="ReportParamsGenerateButton" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

This way you could do `document.form1.ReportParamsGenerateButton.disabled = true` without problem.